# How do I get a group from a partially failing Regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I want to pass some text to a class and have it return a number and a grade of that text.

Now, if there is no grade given, the class is supposed to return the number and a grade that is 0.0

My Problem now is that I am extracting that data with a regex(group).
Once the Pattern doesn't match the whole text, I am not able to retrieve the number anymore.

An example text input without a grade would be:

```
2456272 Max Mustermann 20.02.1968
2456272 would be the number
A grade would be at the very end of the input
```

My code so far:

```
static final String REGEX = "^(?<studentnumber>\\d{7})" // start with student number
            + ".*" // anything in between
            + "\\s+" // separated by at least one space
            + "(?<grade>10(\\.0)?|\\d([.,]\\d)?)" // 10(.0)? or one digit and optionally comma or period followed one digits.
            + "$"; // and nothing else


    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    private final Matcher matcher;

    /**
     * Construct a GradeFilter from a string (line).
     *
     * @param line to read
     */
    public GradeCapture(String line) {
        matcher = PATTERN.matcher(line);
        matcher.matches();
    }

    /**
     * Create a tuple. Use AbstractMap. SimpleEntry as implementing class.
     * @return the tuple.
     */
    public AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Double> getResult() {
        if (hasResult()) {
            return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(studentId(), grade());
        }
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(studentId(), 0D);
    }

    /**
     * Does the line contain the required data?
     * @return whether there is a match
     */
    public boolean hasResult() {
        Integer studentId = studentId();
        Double grade = grade();
        if (studentId == null || grade == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /**
     * Get the grade, if any. 
     *
     * @return the grade or null
     */
    public Double grade() {
        try {
            String grade = matcher.group("grade");
            grade = grade.replaceAll(",", ".");
            return Double.parseDouble(grade);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the student id, if any.
     *
     * @return the student id or null when no match.
     */
    public Integer studentId() {
        try {
            String studentnumber = matcher.group("studentnumber");
            return Integer.parseInt(studentnumber);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

All I want is to retrieve the matcher group "studentnumber" when a part of the matching is failing.

Comment: Remove the `^` at the beginning and the `$` at the end. They match the start and end of your input, respectively.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post an example that **does not** contain a grade.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work, I still get null for the "studentnumber" group

Comment: 1) Do what you do now, if it fails:
2) Run this regexp to get the number: "^(?<studentnumber>\\d{7})";

Comment: I did edit the example.

Comment: @AlfNielsen That is a working solution, but I feel like there should be a way around it. Isn't it possible to extract one group from the String without having to create a new Regex? It's the last part of an excercise I'm doing and I don't think that this is the intended solution.

Comment: Add a ? after the parentes to make the Grade optional. ? means 0 or 1 of what ever came before including a "group" like the grade with parentes:
"(?<grade>10(\\.0)?|\\d([.,]\\d)?)?"

Comment: @AlfNielsen If I do that, all the lines that contain a grade won't read that grade anymore. The problem seems to be that there is no whitespace when there is no grade. But if the whitespace is not a requirement, it will read the date as the grade. And I can't figure out how to adjust the regex for that problem. Edit: That means that the adding the "?" after the parantheses will only work, if there is a whitespace at the very end of the String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the pattern of text that ends the string when the grade is not present, and that pattern obviously cannot be `\b\d+\.\d+$`. In the example that is a date in a particular format. If all strings contained such a date followed by either the end of the line or a space followed by a grade at the end of the line you could match the regex

```
^(\d+).*\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s*(\d+\.\d+)?$
```

[Demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydhabbyr) (click on "Java")

The regex has two capture groups. The first holds the string of digits at the beginning of the line. If the grade is present the second capture group will hold it; if not, the second capture group will be null. Your Java code need only set the grade to the contents of capture group 2 if it is not null; else set it to `0.0`.

Comment: Readers: in Java, how does one test if a capture group is `null`? By testing if it contains an empty string, as in some other languages?

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't 100% what I needed, but I guess some context was missing. There was the possibilty to add several grades but I only needed the last one (same grade different format). But slightly editing what you did made it work. It basically became this: ^(?<studentnumber>\d{7}).*(\d{2}|\d)\.(\d{2}|\d)\.\d{4}(.*\s+(?<grade>10(\.0)?|\d([.,]\d)?)?)?$ . The number format wasn't the same as you suggested, thats the change in the decimals.

Comment: PR, I'm glad you found it helpful.

Comment: I [tested](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyd7eze6r) your regex and found only one small problem (test string 9) which can be corrected by adding a word break after `^(?<studentnumber>\d{7})`. [This regex](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyd7eze6r) is an alternative, provided the grade, if present, follows the date with one or more intervening spaces.